# A restaurant has 15 tables. Given that 70% of booked guests show up, how many reservations can be made to limit the risk of beeing overbooked?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables

I have this problem which I need some help with.

> "A restaurant has 15 tables, and it is known that 70% of guests who
>   make reservations actually show up. To compensate for this, the
>   restaurant has a policy of taking more than 15 reservations, thus
>   running the risk of become overbooked. How many reservations can they
>   take to limit this risk to at most 5%?"

I'm trying to solve the problem in the following way, please explain where my reasoing goes wrong.

If we consider each (booked) person that can possibly show up to be a Bernoulli trial, which we denote $Y_i$, we can note that $P(Y_i = 1) = 0.7 \forall i=1,2,...,N$, where $N$ is the number of trials in our "experiment". If we now consider $X$ to be the number of succesive trials (i.e. the number of guests that actually shows up) $X$ is clearly a binomial distribution with parameters $n=N$ and $p=0.7$. We now want to find the number of trials, $N$ (i.e. number of reservations).

So, we know that $E[X]=$"The expected number of guests showing up" should satisfy $E[X] \leqq 15 + 15*0.05$ (I think it is here I'm doing something wrong) and because we know that (for binomial distribution) $E[X] = Np$ we can simply solve for N. This gives the number of reservations to be less than 22.5. The book says the answer should be 17. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, try it.  Suppose you made $22$ reservations.  Calculate the probability that the number of actual customers is $≤15$.  Is it at least $.95$?

Comment: Note:  with $22$ people the expectation is $.7\times 22=15.4>15$ so your restaurant has a big problem.

Comment: hmm ok. So am I completely wrong in my attempted solution?

Comment: Yes.  You need to find $N$ , the number of reservations, such that the probability that more than $15$ show up is $≤.05$.  Trial and error is easy here.  For much larger samples, you can use the normal approximation to the binomial.

Comment: Ok, so you mean that I need to find $N$ such that$ \sum\limits_{i=k}^{15} {N\choose k} p^k (1-p)^{N-k} \leqq 0.05$ ? I actually came this far before I tried the solution above, but I had no idea how to solve this for N without using e.g. Matlab

Comment: It should say $ \leqq 0.95 $ above

Comment: For any particular $N$ a simple calculator should do it.  Excel, for example, can easily handle it.  We already know the answer is significantly less than $22$...really, it's a trivial search.

Comment: Almost all probability and statistics problems require numerical work...you can't avoid that stuff forever.

Comment: Worth noting:  always look for ways to simplify a numerical calculation.  In this case, for instance, it has to be easier to work with the cases  $16,17,\cdots, N$ show up instead of $1,\cdots, 15$,  It's a shorter sum!

Comment: Alright. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want $P(X \le 15) \ge .95,$ where $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n, .7).$
In R statistical software `pnorm` is a binomial CDF. (Ignore brackets `[ ]`.)

```
n = 15:20;  p.ok = pbinom(15, n, .7)
cbind(n, p.ok)
      n      p.ok
[1,] 15 1.0000000
[2,] 16 0.9966767
[3,] 17 0.9807249
[4,] 18 0.9400478
[5,] 19 0.8668290
[6,] 20 0.7624922
```

Seems 17 is safe and 18 isn't.

If you are unable or unwilling to use
software, a normal approximation with continuity correction would suffice.
If $n = 17$ and $p = .7,$ then
$$P(X \le 15.5) = P\left(\frac{X - np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} 
\le \frac{15.5-17(.7)}{\sqrt{17(.7)(.3)}}\right)
\approx P(Z \le 1.91) = 0.9719.$$
So 17 is safe, and then you could try 18 (which gives about 0.93, and so isn't safe).

More generally, using a normal approximation, you need $n$ such that
$\frac{15.5-.7n}{\sqrt{.21n}} > 1.645.$